# The way to start Microsoft Edge from C++ in Windows 10 does not work in Windows Server 2016

Tags: c++, windows-10, shellexecuteex, windows-server-2016

The following file test.cc is to launch Microsoft Edge with specific URL:

```
#include <Windows.h>

int main()
{
    SHELLEXECUTEINFOW sei = { sizeof sei };
    sei.lpVerb = L"open";
    sei.lpFile = L"microsoft-edge:http://www.stackoverflow.com";
    ShellExecuteExW(&sei);
}
```

Compile with:

```
cl test.cc /link shell32.lib
```

It works in Windows 10 (Edge opened to specific URL), but in Windows Server 2016 this program pops up an error window:

Title: `microsoft-edge:http://www.stackoverflow.com`

Content: `This file does not have a program associated with it for performing this action. Please install a program or, if one is already installed, create an association in the Default Programs control panel.`

I checked "Default Programs" in control panel and already chose "Set this program as default" in Microsoft Edge page.

Comment: Do you have another browser installed _and_ set as default? If not, you should simply drop the reference to Edge in the `lpFile` param.

Comment: The OS also comes with IE and I installed Firefox later. These two are not set as default browser. I tried removing "microsoft-edge:" from lpFile and the same error window will pop out except the title changed from "microsoft-edge:http://www.stackoverflow.com" to "http://www.stackoverflow.com". Has it worked on your Windows Server 2016?

Comment: Bugger! No, sorry I dont have 2k16 and was presumptuous enough to assume it would do the trick. Perhaps the changed functionality is a security 'feature'.